# How Do I Enable HTTPS on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment for Parse Server Example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, stripe-payments, webhooks, parse-server

I am trying to enable SSL/TLS on my Parse Server on AWS so that i can receive Webhooks from Stripe.

I created a self signed certificate on my using openssl, but when i tried to send a web hook with stripe i received the following error.

```
Invalid TLS
```

My Parse server index.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  // push: pushConfig,
  // filesAdapter: filesAdapter,
  push:{
    ios:{
      pfx:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // P12 file only
      bundleId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  // change to match bundleId
      production: false // dev certificate
    }
  },
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

How can I enable the https?

Comment: Stripe is almost certainly not going to accept a self-signed HTTPS certificate. It needs to be a certificate that is trusted. That is, if you can load it in a browser without security warnings, then it will work.

Comment: thanks for your comment @vcsjones

Comment: Are you using a load-balanced Elastic Beanstalk environment? In other words, do you have an Elastic Load Balancer? If so, forget about creating certs and configuring your server, just obtain a free SSL cert from the AWS ACM service and install it on the ELB.

Comment: What domain should i use for the AWS ACM?  And thank you for your answer @MarkB

Comment: @J.P one that you have purchased. You aren't ever going to be able to create a valid SSL certificate that won't generate errors or warnings in a browser until you purchase your own domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get certificate from a trusted source . Otherwise even browsers will flag it as untrusted. Also while setting up https server you need to include this line of code :

```
 https.createServer({
         key: fs.readFileSync('Your-private-key.pem'),
         cert: fs.readFileSync('your-crt-file.crt')
     }, app).listen(3001,function(){
         console.log('https server started on port 3001');
     });
```

Also if you want to enforce https i would suggest you to look into express-sslify